# Scrolling in View Pager

Tags: android

I have an activity in which I have taken single tab layout and content of this tab layout is contained inside a viewpager.
This is my part of the code of main activity containing the tab layout and the viewpager.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/materialup.tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/selecteditem"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#0000"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"

    app:tabSelectedTextColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />
        ​
<!-- The top margin value equals half height of the blue box -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/materialup.viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

and for the content of this viewpager I have taken a Fragment class which contains a expandable list view, here is the part of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dip"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frstll"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ExpandableListView                   //list view taken for list items
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:childDivider="#f4f4f4"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:groupIndicator="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that when I touch on the tab(the green portion in the image), the layout scrolls perfectly but when I click on the expandable listview's part (the portion with white background in the image) it does not scroll.

So how can I achieve scrolling by touching on the expandable list part?

[image]

This is the layout I have acheived using the above code.

I want to know why the default scrolling feature of expandable listview is not working here in my code.

Should I change my Main Activity's layout or a minor change in the expandable listview's code in my fragment class?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Please add touchlistener on ExpandableListView**

```
yourRecyclerview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It does not scrolls the whole screen

Comment: put your layout(image and expandablelistview) inside single parent "scrollview" and set it to fill:viewport=true